# How can I listen and speak simultaneously using Azure Cognitive services

Tags: python, azure, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I am trying to build a chatbot, that is capable of speaking and listening simultaneously. I am working with azure cognitive services and currently use two functions to listen and speak:

Speaking:

```
def speak(input,voice="en-US-ChristopherNeural"):

audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioOutputConfig(use_default_speaker=True)
speech_config.speech_synthesis_voice_name=voice
speech_synthesizer = speechsdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

speech_synthesis_result = speech_synthesizer.speak_text_async(input).get()
if speech_synthesis_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
    cancellation_details = speech_synthesis_result.cancellation_details
    print("Azure Speech synthesis canceled: {}".format(cancellation_details.reason))

return True
```

Listening:

```
def listen(language):
speech_config.speech_recognition_language=language
audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(use_default_microphone=True)
speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

print("Speak into your microphone.")
speech_recognition_result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once_async().get()

if speech_recognition_result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
    print("Recognized: {}".format(speech_recognition_result.text))

    return speech_recognition_result.text
```

I want to be capable of interrupting a spoken text, if the user starts speaking. This means I have to constantly listen to the microphone input to determine an attempt in speech.

I am currently trying multithreading, however the examples I tried are all getting blocked by the line:

```
speech_synthesis_result = speech_synthesizer.speak_text_async(input).get()
```

This is what I have so far, however it does not speak anything:

```
import asyncio
import os
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk
from azure.cognitiveservices.speech import SpeechConfig, SpeechSynthesisOutputFormat, SpeechSynthesizer

# Replace with your own subscription key and region identifier
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=os.environ.get('SPEECH_KEY'), region=os.environ.get('SPEECH_REGION'))

# Set up the speech synthesizer


# Define the phrase to be spoken
phrase = "Hello, I'm a chatbot. How can I help you today? You can interrupt me whenever you want"

async def listen_for_user_input():

    speech_config.speech_recognition_language="en-US-ChristopherNeural"
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(use_default_microphone=True)
    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)

    result = await speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition_async()
    if result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
        print("Recognized: {}".format(result.text))
        await speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition_async()
    pass

async def speak_phrase(phrase):
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioOutputConfig(use_default_speaker=True)
    synthesizer = speechsdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
    # Speak the defined phrase
    result = await synthesizer.speak_text_async(phrase)
    if result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
        cancellation_details = result.cancellation_details
        print("Azure Speech synthesis canceled: {}".format(cancellation_details.reason))
       

# Start the program
async def main():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(speak_phrase(phrase))
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(listen_for_user_input())
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait([task1, task2], return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
    for task in pending:
        task.cancel()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Speech SDK for Python as of today (version 1.x.x) do not support asyncio/await for its asynchronous methods, we are working on to make that support in the next major release. See below alternative way and modified methods in your example of running speech-to-text and text-to-speech in parallel.

```
import threading

def listen_for_user_input():
    print("Start listen_for_user_input")
    transcription_done = threading.Event()
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(use_default_microphone=True)

    def recognized_cb(evt):
        if evt.result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
            print('RECOGNIZED: {}'.format(evt))
        elif evt is not None and evt.result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
            print('NOMATCH: {}'.format(evt))
        transcription_done.set()

    def canceled_cb(evt):
        try:
            if evt.result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
                cancellation_details = evt.result.cancellation_details
                print('CANCELED: {}'.format(cancellation_details.reason))
                if cancellation_details.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
                    print('Error details: {}'.format(cancellation_details.error_details))
                    transcription_done.set()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
    speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(recognized_cb)
    speech_recognizer.canceled.connect(canceled_cb)

    speech_recognizer.start_continuous_recognition_async()
    transcription_done.wait()
    speech_recognizer.stop_continuous_recognition_async()
    print("Stop listen_for_user_input")

def speak_phrase():
    print("Start speak_phrase")
    audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioOutputConfig(use_default_speaker=True)
    synthesizer = speechsdk.SpeechSynthesizer(speech_config=speech_config, audio_config=audio_config)
    # Speak the defined phrase
    result = synthesizer.speak_text_async(phrase).get()
    if result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
        cancellation_details = result.cancellation_details
        print("Azure Speech synthesis canceled: {}".format(cancellation_details.reason))
    print("Stop speak_phrase")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Start main program")
    # create threads for parallel execution
    p1 = threading.Thread(target=speak_phrase)
    p2 = threading.Thread(target=listen_for_user_input)

    # start both threads
    p1.start()
    p2.start()

    # wait for both threads to finish
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    print("Stop main program")
```

Comment: Wow, thank you. This works great. Would you happen to know if it is possible to stop the text-to-speech the moment the listen function detects the start of a sentence?